# Как очистить данные внутри inline клавиатуры?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Клавиатура добавляет в себя столько кнопок сколько имен в бд sqlite при вызове функции. Не могу найти метод для aiogram который очищал бы клавиатуру перед наполнением. Как это делает в листах .clear()

```py
async def set_kb():
    await (p := gather(db_show_players()))
    for i in p.result()[0]:
        in_group_kb_players.add(InlineKeyboardButton(text=""+str(i[0]), callback_data=i[1]))
```

Сейчас если вызвать функцию несколько раз она будем дублировать кнопки (.clean() не работает)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет такого метода который очищает маркап. Единственное что вы можете сделать это нормально создать новый маркап и изменить сообщение с помощью `edit_reply_markup`

```
@dp.callback_query_handler()
async def sad(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    await call.answer()
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    for button in [...]:
        markup.add(InlineKeyboardButton(text=f" {button[0]}", callback_data=button[1]))
    await call.message.edit_reply_markup(reply_markup=markup)
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. Исправил!